# Parent process variables inside Child process in Perl

Tags: perl, process, global-variables, system, scribe

- I have a script `execute.pl` and it calls `child.pl` through `system` call.
- I am creating an object of `AppLogger` in execute.pl
- This `AppLogger` is package and an interface to my `Scribe` Logging server
- Now in this `AppLogger` I am establishing a connection to my Scribe
  Logging server and has various funtions like `sendlog` which sends logs to server.

  **`execute.pl:`**

  ```
  use AppLogger;
  use strict;
  use warnings;

  my $logger = new AppLogger;
  system("perl child.pl")
  ```

As I know `system` is a `OS` call and `child.pl` will be completly different process but still Is there a way I can access `$logger` ie `AppLogger` object inside child.pl without re-creating an connection object each time I want to log.

Comment: pass the variables as arguments and capture them with `my $var = shift;` or `my ($var1, $var2 ...) = $_;`

Comment: yes I need to access my object in parent inside my child process

Comment: You can achieve the same using the `eval` instead of `system` call. But it may not be a good  idea to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `system` is a wrapper around `fork`+`exec`+`wait`. `exec` replaces the program executing in the process, including its heap (memory).